# What is the difference between setting the environment variables in these 2 ways?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, bash, environment-variables

For a project I'm working on, we require nginx and lua, and we start it like this:

```
MYVAR1=some_value MYVAR2=some_value /usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx -p `pwd`/ -c nginx.conf
```

And everything works. If, instead, we do this:

```
export MYVAR1=some_value
export MYVAR2=some_value
/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx -p `pwd`/ -c nginx.conf
```

Then, a lua script running inside the worker process complains that MYVAR1 and MYVAR2 are not set. What is the difference between these 2, and why isn't nginx+lua picking them up in the 2nd version?

Comment: Note that if your shell is `/bin/sh`, that shell may not support the `export var=val` syntax. You may have to write `var=val; export var`. The main difference is that the first only export the variables for nginx and its children; the second will make the vars available for any process that shell spawns.

Answer (score 2):

If running under `bash`, there should be no difference, other than that `MYVAR1` and `MYVAR2` will continue to be set to the same value once `/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx` is finished executing. The first syntax you showed will only have the variables exist for the lifetime of `nginx`'s execution.

Now, if you're not using `bash`, (for example, `/bin/sh`, or another POSIX-compliant shell) you may need an alternate syntax, setting the environment variables before `export`ing them:

```
MYVAR1=some_value
export MYVAR1

MYVAR2=some_value
export MYVAR2
```

I'm not sure if you're doing this from a shell terminal or via a shell script, but you can determine this via:

```
ps -ef | grep $$ | grep -v grep
```

If it's `/bin/sh`, or some other shell, this is your problem. If you're doing this inside a shell script, you can change the shebang line (`#!/...` at the top of the file) to `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh`, or use sh-compliant syntax.